# Xcode Cocoa Pod is not generating framework directory in Derived Data folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have created brand new project with ObjC, Storyboard.I executed pod init. write below lines in podfile.

```
target 'wwwww' do
pod 'AFNetworking'
end
```

Project target name is 'wwwww'. I executed pod install. pod succesfully installed in terminal. I ran workspace again, now on build ,i am getting this error.

```
directory not found for option '-L/Users/loginname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wwwww-gzppqegvhfhibfcbtqvnsesrltlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking'
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
```

When I visited above path, Afnetworking is not generated at above path. Please guide.

Comment: I was doing one mistake. I added arm64 in excluded architectures for some reason. I removed that and now Afnetworking framework is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Just move file inside Framework folder to outside, for example i have Alamofire framework folder, the i put Alamofire.framework to move this otside [image]